# How to change the default icon provider in Blazor app?

Tags: c#, css, icons, blazor

When you first make a Blazor project, the default icon provider is Iconify, with their open [icon pack](https://iconify.design/icon-sets/oi/).

> How can I change the icon provider?

Most sites provide some `JavaScript` to include in an html page, which I don't use since I'm using a `Blazor` page.

> What do I need to do to switch my provider over?

Comment: Each one will have its own assets that need to be referenced. What have you tried? Try adding what one you want to use, what you tried and what error you got

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The icons are comming from `@import url('open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css');` from **site.css**

Import different icons

I have used Material Icons

1.Imported material icon in **site.css**
`@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons');`

2.Use the Material Icons

Example:

```
<div class="@NavMenuCssClass" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
    <ul class="nav flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <i class="material-icons">
                    accessibility
                </i> Home
            </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="counter">
                <i class="material-icons">autorenew</i>
                Counter
            </NavLink>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

What worked for is to put the following link on the head tag, then I was able to get the icons

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

then access the icons like so

```
<i class="material-icons">face</i>
```

For more info check this [document](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#icon-font-for-the-web)

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css"  />

<i class="fa-solid fa-cog fa-spin me-3" aria-hidden="true"></i> Setting
```

font-awesome

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome

Comment: Welcome to SO!. Please add some explanation. Imparting the underlying logic is more important than just giving the code, because it helps the OP and other readers fix this and similar issues themselves.